# "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')" error after React 18 upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am currently working on upgrading our react codebase from v16.12 to the latest v18 release and I am receiving the following error when switching between components,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')
    at eval (index.js:381:295102)
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22927:5)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23095:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountInsideDeletedTreeOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:25093:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffectsInsideOfDeletedTree_begin (react-dom.development.js:25043:5)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24951:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24936:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27033:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26979:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26930:5)
```

When I peek into index.js:381, I see the following block,

```
        Object(De.useEffect)(function() {
            if (H(),
            null !== E.current)
                return E.current.addEventListener("scroll", t),
                window.addEventListener("scroll", n),
                window.addEventListener("resize", t),
                window.addEventListener("resize", n),
                window.addEventListener("resize", H),
                function() {
                    E.current.removeEventListener("scroll", t),
                    window.removeEventListener("scroll", n),
                    window.removeEventListener("resize", t),
                    window.removeEventListener("resize", n),
                    window.removeEventListener("resize", H)
                }
        }, []),
```

To attempt to resolve, I go ahead and add conditional logic to ensure the listener exists before attempting to remove but it has no effect. I've even attempted to just comment out the removeEventListener's as a test and no effect,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (filtersContainerRef.current !== null) {
      filtersContainerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', removeActiveFilter);
      window.addEventListener('scroll', setFiltersContainerOffsetTop);
      window.addEventListener('resize', removeActiveFilter);
      window.addEventListener('resize', setFiltersContainerOffsetTop);

      return () => {
        // filtersContainerRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', removeActiveFilter);
        // window.removeEventListener('scroll', setFiltersContainerOffsetTop);
        // window.removeEventListener('resize', removeActiveFilter);
        // window.removeEventListener('resize', setFiltersContainerOffsetTop);
      };
    }
  }, []);
```

Could this be a webpack issue? It feels like the changes aren't getting picked up/built by webpack but it says so in the console,

```
./src/components/Audiences/Filters/Index.js 9.46 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 1175 ms
```

I've also upgraded webpack and webpack-cli to the latest versions to no effect as well. Any pointers or next steps I could try on this one would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you depend on element ref, you should not work with `E.current` but the value it returns the time `useEffect` get called. `E.current` in mount and the cleanup function can be different, this is why you should work with its current value inside the effect, instead of its reference

```
useEffect(() => {
   const el = E.current
   el.addEventListener(...)
   return () => {
      el.removeEventListener(...)
   }
}, [])
```

This way you ensure that `el` in effect and `el` in cleanup function have the same value

If your element gets unmounted from the DOM, no need to clear its events, they will be removed together with the element

Comment: Would that logic still apply even if I am using const filtersContainerRef = useRef(null) above?

Comment: Yes. filtersContainerRef reference never changes. But the 'current' property can change. This way you are not working with that dynamic value, you are working with the value that you get on mount.

Comment: Okay so I updated, and still seeing the same error,

`const el = filtersContainerRef.current;`
and still seeing the same the same error.. This one is definitely stumping me at the moment

Comment: It is impossible to see the same error if you did what I mentioned. It is impossible 'el' to be null in cleanup function and an element on mount. If it was null, it would crash on addEventListener instead of removeEventListener.

Comment: Yeah I agree. There must be something going on with my webpack build or something. Thanks!